# Loop hole of finding rank using Minor method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

According to definition of **Rank**,

Rank is the number of dimensions in column space of a matrix.  So rank can be found from reduced echelon form.

But in another definition, that is the reduction of the matrix to **Minors**, the size of the largest non-zero minor is the rank.

Taking this example,

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Applying the first definition , it can be seen the  ***column 2*** and ***column 3*** are linearly independent and hence rank is **2**.

But upon applying the second defination all the ***2x2*** minors are zero, which by definition gives a rank **1**.

I know rank **2** is the correct answer. So what is it that I'm missing ? Are both these definitions correct ?

Comment: All $2 \times 2$ minors are not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first column and the second row. The resulting $2\times2$ minor is $1$.

Comment: ok got it , thank you